# I have a update panel inside a tabpanel of tabcontainer. I want to show it on new next panel tabpanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a update panel inside a `tabpanel` of `tabcontainer`. I want to show it on new next panel `tabpanel`

please help me i am a new in jquery

Comment: Next tabpanel i given a imagelink button. when i click on that image its popup on there.

Comment: I thine `clone` will help, check that https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Add some more code here and explain what you want more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment i will try it

Comment: I have update panel inside tab panel of tab container. I want to show this update panel in another tab.